# automatic refresh of asp.net Cache each night

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have fairly big ArrayList which I want to have recalculated and put in Cache each night around 2.
How can I achieve that? There's option to set time of expiration, but that doesn't cover up my needs.

Comment: Please tell us _why_ normal cache expiration won't work for you as an alternate solution will be excessively complex in comparison.

Comment: Andrew, I just realized that I could create static class manager for this Cache, set apropriate expiration date (now + whatever it's needed to next 2 in the night) and attach proper CacheItemRemovedCallback. This way, the whole Cache will be automatically recalculated each night... True?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have the cache object have a FileDependency and have some scheduled task change the file once per day.

It may not be "pretty" BUT if you have some scheduled task (or SQL Server Job or some other process that can run a file) that updates the data that is used to create the data that is contained in this ArrayList, an appropriate option would be to alter the file in that (code, SQL Server Job, etc).